# Simple jquery caption not working

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I am trying to make a simple little caption box that fades in to 50% of the total width of the element when you mouseover the element, and stays there until you mouseout of the element.

It's working somewhat, but the problem is when I move my mouse over a link inside the .caption div,  it's fading in and out (flashing), almost like it's treating the caption as a seperate element even though it's inside the main element. It also seems to randomly flash a couple times if I mouseout and mouseover quickly.

Here's my CSS:

```
.thumbs li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 305px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.thumbs li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.thumbs li .caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.thumbs li .caption a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('.thumbs li').mouseover(function() {      
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(500);
});

$('.thumbs li').mouseout(function() {       
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
<li>

    <img src="images/1.gif" alt="" />

    <div class="caption">

        <h4>Cycliner</h4>

        <p>
        <a href="#">Visit website</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#">View project</a>
        </p>

    </div>

</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the mouseleave function instead of mouseout

http://jsfiddle.net/gygHg/

```
$('.thumbs li').mouseover(function() {      
$(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(500);
});

$('.thumbs li').mouseleave(function() {       
$(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.thumbs li').mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).find('.caption').stop(false,true).fadeIn(400);
});
$('.thumbs li').mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).find('.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(400);
});
```

The stop will help your animation from flickering and persisting. I've made a jQuery plugin very similar to yours :)

Comment: it didnt stop the flickering but helped alot.

Comment: That's odd... I don't have the same problem on my script using that technique. But I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of the events you are binding to currently. Those trigger on the mouse entering the boundaries of the element they are attached to and won't re-trigger due to inner elements.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/cdeszaq/WGaLk/1/)